# which ruby twitter library/gem to use?

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

there is a list of  [ruby gems for twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries#Ruby)

could anybody recommend me one that is good to start to learn/use? that have some history of development etc etc?

I want to the stuff below on my linux box

- search for keywords and follow
- autofollow
- rewteet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd suggest the [twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) by john nunemaker. it supports search and retweeting. not sure about autofollow though. there's another list of api clients at the [ruby toolbox](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients.html).